# Filter a List by taking reference from another List in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've two lists, one is storing the category of cars(Like SUV, Sedan, minivans etc).
And the second list is storing all the details of cars and it consist category as well.

I'm using nested listview where first listview is showing car's category in Verticle manner and inside of it, I want to show details of the car belongs to the same category in horizonatal manner.

Here's the Code Snippet:

```
 ListView.builder(                                         //This is First list with only Category name
                             shrinkWrap: true,
                         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: categoriesOnlyList.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context, index1) {
                           return
                             Column(
                               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                               children: [
                                 Padding(
                                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                   child: Container(
                                     margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                     child: Text(
                                       categoriesOnlyList[index1].Name,
                                       textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                       style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70,
                                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                           fontSize: 18),
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ),
                       Container(
                                height: 300,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                             ),
                                child: ListView.builder(             //This the Second List with all details.
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: categoryItemList.length,
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                    return categoriesOnlyList[index1].Name==categoryItemList[index].CategoryName
                                          && categoryItemList[index].ID.startsWith("105")?     // Here I'm applying condition
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                          child: Text(categoryItemList[index].Name,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),),
                                        ),
                                      ):Container();
                                }),
                              )

                               ],
                             );

                      }),
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Somehow I'm able to achieve this with the above code but facing another problem with horizontal Scrollable Items,asked on link given below.

[ListView scroll offset issue in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322644/listview-scroll-offset-issue-in-flutter).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your problem, I think this might fix it:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  final list = [
    'BMW',
    'Toyota',
    'Testa',
    'Ford',
    'Fiat',
    'BMW',
    'Toyota',
    'Testa',
    'Ford',
    'Fiat'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (_, __) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 60,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Text(list[index]),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: list.length,
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

## Update(1)

```
class Car {
  final String company;
  final String category;

  Car(this.company, this.category);
}

void main() {
  var list = [
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
  ];

  Map<String,List<Car>> groupedLists = {};

  list.forEach((car) {
    if (groupedLists['${car.category}'] == null) {
      groupedLists['${car.category}'] = <Car>[];
    }

    groupedLists['${car.category}'].add(car);
  });

  print(groupedLists);
}
```

the result is:

```
{
SUV: [Instance of 'Car', Instance of 'Car'], 
SEDAN: [Instance of 'Car']
}
```

and here is the full flutter code to display these groups:

```
class Car {
  final String company;
  final String category;

  Car(this.company, this.category);
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  final list = [
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
    Car('Toyata', 'SUV'),
    Car('BMW', 'SEDAN'),
    Car('Tesla', 'SUV'),
  ];

  Map<String, List<Car>> groupedLists = {};

  void groupMyList() {
    list.forEach((car) {
      if (groupedLists['${car.category}'] == null) {
        groupedLists['${car.category}'] = <Car>[];
      }

      groupedLists['${car.category}'].add(car);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    groupMyList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var entry in groupedLists.entries)
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 60,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: entry.value.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: Text(entry.value[index].company),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually this is not what I want, you have not compared the list. They're two lists.

Comment: My main problem is filtering the list.

Comment: do you mean that the problem is basically related to dart not flutter, and you have a list of cars with different categories and you want to filter/group them?

Comment: Yes, Exactly  I want the same.

Comment: Check out the updated answer if it's the right one =D

Comment: This code works fine with this data list, but when I'm trying with firebase data list it's getting failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219505/discussion-between-praveen-gupta-and-nour-shobier).